# How to fill a variable inside a map - Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to read a text file and read it to save its values in a variable type

`Map[Int, collection.mutable.Map[Int, Double]]`.

I have done it with a foreach and a broadcast variable, and it works properly in my local machine but it does not in a yarn-cluster. Foreach task takes too much time with the same task that in my local computer takes only 1 minute.

```
val data = sc.textFile(fileOriginal)

val dataRDD = parsedData.map(s => s.split(';').map(_.toDouble)).cache()

val datos = collection.mutable.Map[Int, collection.mutable.Map[Int, Double]]()
val bcDatos = sc.broadcast(datos)


dataRDD.foreach { case x =>

  if (bcDatos.value.contains(x.apply(0).toInt)) {
    bcDatos.value(x.apply(0).toInt).put(x.apply(1).toInt, x.apply(2) / x.apply(3) * 100)

  } else {
    bcDatos.value.put(x.apply(0).toInt, collection.mutable.Map((x.apply(1).toInt, x.apply(2) / x.apply(3) * 100)))
  }
}
```

My question is: How can I do the same, but using map? Can I "fill" a variable with that structure inside a map?

Thank you

Comment: the "working" part shouldn't work either - broadcast is meant for **read-only** values, you can'y update a braodcasted mutable map and expect it to reflect a single map - each executor will update its own copy and these copies will vanish once job is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Spark - you should *never* try using mutable structures in distributed manner - that's simply not supported. If you mutate a variable  created in driver code (whether using broadcast or not), a *copy* of that variable will be mutated on each executor separately, and you'll never be able to "merge" these mutated partial results and send them back to the driver.

Instead - you should *transform* your RDD into a new (immutable!) RDD with the data you need.

If I managed to follow your logic correctly - this would give you the map you need:

```
// assuming dataRDD has type RDD[Array[Double]] and each Array has at least 4 items:
val result: Map[Int, Map[Int, Double]] = dataRDD
  .keyBy(_(0).toInt)
  .mapValues(arr => Map(arr(1).toInt -> arr(2) / arr(3) * 100))
  .reduceByKey((a, b) => a) // you probably want to "merge" maps "a" and "b" here, but your code doesn't seem to do that now either
  .collectAsMap()
```

Comment: Thank you!! That worked fine!! I had just to modify .reduceByKey((a, b) => a++b) because I needed all the values from the map. Thanks!!