# Spark Scala: Generating list of DataFrame based on values in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a rdd containing values, each of those values will be passed to a function `generate_df(num:Int)` to create a dataframe. So essentially in the end we will have a list of dataframes stored in a list buffer like this `var df_list_example = new ListBuffer[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]()`.

First I will show the code and result of doing it using a list instead of RDD:

```
var df_list = new ListBuffer[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]()

for (i <- list_values) //list_values contains values
{
  df_list += generate_df(i)
}
```

Result:

> df_list:
>   scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] =
>   ListBuffer([value: int], [value: int], [value: int])

However, when I am using RDD which is very essential for my use case I am having issue:

```
var df_rdd_list = new ListBuffer[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]()

//rdd_values contains values
rdd_values.map( i => df_rdd_list += generate_df(i)  )
```

Result:

> df_rdd_list:
>   scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] =
>   ListBuffer()

Basically the list buffer remains empty and cannot store dataframes unlike when I am using list of values instead of rdd of values. Mapping using rdd is essential for my original use case.

Comment: Why do you want to convert an RDD into a list of single-record DataFrames? This can't work as the RDD is a _distributed_ collection and you're trying to create a _local_ list - don't you prefer creating a _single_ DataFrame with one _record_ per each record in the RDD?

Comment: @TzachZohar the issue is each value in the RDD is used to query from a database (Neo4j) and get multiple rows of dataframe from there (each of different length). If I can get one single dataframe that will be fantastic. Afterall, that's the final goal. Essentially, for each value in the RDD I will get dataframe with different rows length but in the end I need one unified dataframe. Any suggestion to achieve that?

Comment: So what's the contents of this RDD, and how large would it get (number of records)? If it's small (say, < 10K?), just `collect` it into a local List and `map` that list using `generate_df`; Otherwise, it sounds like this won't be too efficient anyway if you plan on performing thousands of Neo4j queries...

Comment: RDD contains distinct IDs. `generate_df` uses neo4j-spark connector to create dataframe. Each of these IDs will be used to return the subgraph it belongs to (so if there are 5 nodes in the subgraph then there will be 5 rows in the dataframe). It can go well beyond `10k` but still I would like know what you will suggest if it is below that. Let's say even if I collect the RDD to list, I want to take advantage of the worker nodes I have using neo4j-spark connector so that queries can be done in distributed way. I have achieved that for insertion but for this input is the issue. @TzachZohar

Comment: @TzachZohar I must also add. Its not one record in DataFrame for each record in RDD. For each record in RDD it can have one or more records and the number of records depends on the value in the RDD. The mapping is not 1:1.

Comment: First, the direct answer to your actual question ("[why does] the ListBuffer remain empty") can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39899715/5344058) - you can't update local collections from distributed operations on RDDs/DataFrames. Second,  although I'm not too familiar with neo4j-spark connector, I'm pretty sure it's meant to be used from the Driver and not from the worker machines, since you generally can't create DataFrames outside the driver (a DataFrame, like an RDD, is a driver-side abstraction over a collection whose _data_ is distributed over the worker nodes).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150861/discussion-between-tzach-zohar-and-sjishan).